# Kuberentes Volume to upload and download files with multinodes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage

i’ve a question about the Volumes (I use GoogleCloud).

Reading the doc if I specify `ReadWriteOnce` (i use VolumeClaim) it seems that only one node can have the writing right. And the option with `Multi` is not yet supported by cloud vendors.

Now, i’ve the case where I’ve to serve files that people upload. The upload is `chunk` based upload, this means that it can be done in parallel. Having more than one node that can serve the purpose of receiving the uploaded chunk, i can have the need that more than on node has the writing right on the volume. Each node stores chunk and one node, in the end, recompose it and create a single file.

What’s the right approach to do that? What should I use?

(should I user cloud storage as a single point for read/write files?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might need to change the volume backend which supports `ReadWriteMany`. The Volume Plugin that supports `ReadWriteMany` are AzureFile, CephFS, GlusterFS, NFS, etc. Find more about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes).

And then for provisioning that you can use the above listed storage on top of GCE.

Comment: The storage types mentioned like NFS or GlusterFS will run on GCE and will be managed by you! You just mention it's endpoint in the GKE.

Comment: in the end i found. I setup a machine with nfs and then connected kubernetes using volume and volumeClaim linked to that machine.